# Why such different and unsymmetrical rules for defining values at which flush to zero and flush to infinity occurs for floating-point?

Tags: java, floating-point

Why `Double.MIN_VALUE == Math.ulp(Double.MIN_VALUE) // 4.9E-324`

while `Double.MAX_VALUE != Math.ulp(Double.MAX_VALUE)`

```
// Double.MAX_VALUE           = 1.7976931348623157E308
// Math.ulp(Double.MAX_VALUE) = 1.9958403095347198E292    !!!
```

*I thought that flush to zero occurs at floating-point values less than `Double.MIN_VALUE - Math.ulp(Double.MIN_VALUE)`.* But this is not true, besides both Double.MIN_VALUE and Math.ulp(Double.MIN_VALUE) are equal. In reality flush to zero occurs at `Math.ulp(Double.MIN_VALUE)/2` exactly and below (smaller than that).

But flush to infinity occurs at `Double.MAX_VALUE + Math.ulp(Double.MAX_VALUE)`. Interesting thing to note is that `Double.MAX_VALUE + Integer.MAX_VALUE ==  Double.MAX_VALUE` (because Integer.MAX_VALUE < Math.ulp(Double.MAX_VALUE) ).

Why logic for flush to zero is different from flush to infinity? I mean w**hy flush to zero is not** `Double.MIN_VALUE - Math.ulp(Double.MIN_VALUE)/2 // same as Double.MIN_VALUE` - ***symmetrically* to flush to infinity which occurs at** `Double.MAX_VALUE + Math.ulp(Double.MAX_VALUE)/2` and `-Double.MAX_VALUE - Math.ulp(Double.MAX_VALUE)/2` ?

My research: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667932/minimum-floating-point-number-closest-to-zero) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448637/how-are-upper-and-lower-bounds-for-floating-point-numbers-determined) are c++ specific only.

Answer (score 1):

The effect you observe is called *gradual underflow*. It was designed into floating-point arithmetic to avoid having bits in numbers that could be parts of greater numbers but could not stand on their own.

Consider this code:

```
if (a == b)
    printf("The divisor is zero.\n");
else
    printf("The quotient is %g.\n", c / (a-b));
```

Consider what happens if `a` is 1.25×2<sup>−1022</sup> and `b` is 1×2<sup>−1022</sup>. `a` and `b` are different, so `a == b` is false. If you subtacted them and got zero because .25×2<sup>−1022</sup> was less than the cutoff, then `c / (a-b)` would cause an exception and produce infinity even if `c` were a small value and the mathematical result were representable. We want this code, where the user tested to avoid an error, to work. Gradual underflow means that, if there is a bit in a value (or multiple bits), we can do arithmetic with that bit (or bits). Subtracting the other bits in the number will leave that bit (or bits), not jump suddenly to zero.

Gradual underflow avoids strange situations where you subtract two numbers and the result jumps in large ways (relative to the magnitudes involved).